# Why does the merge-base matter in a two-way merge?

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand why merge-bases matter in complex three-way merges.  In order to understand *this*, I realized I don't even understand why they matter in two-way merges!

**For Example:** Suppose we have commit `B` on branch "master" and commit `C` on branch "alt".  Suppose further that `B` and `C` are the head commits for each of the branches `master` and `alt`, respectively.  Suppose we wish to merge `C` into `B` to form commit `D` on the master branch.  Suppose finally that commit `A` on the "master" branch is the merge-base of `B` and `C`.

**Question 1:** Why does `A` matter when performing the merge operation?  Can't git just take the contents of `C`'s working directory and merge it into the contents of `B`'s working directory without any reference whatsoever to the content's of `A`'s working directory?

EDIT:

**Question 2:** Suppose there commits in between `C` and `A` and/or commits in between `B` and `A`. Would those commits matter from git's perspective when performing a merge operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've described *is* a three way merge:  `B` and `C` will be merged with knowledge of their common ancestor, `A`.  The common ancestor is used to know what files have been modified between `A` and `B`, thus which changes need to be brought to `C` (and what changes have been made between `A` and `C`, to mark conflicts).

Imagine you did not use the merge base:  now all you have is a pile of files in each side.  If any files differed, they *must* conflict.  If you had a common ancestor, you could determine how some branch has changed the file and promote one side (if `B` has changed a file but `C` has not, merge will take the `B` side when merging.). Without a common ancestor, that can only be a conflict.

Comment: So theoretically, the merge doesn't *need* the merge-base `A`, except insofar as it makes it easier on uses to merge changes (i.e., without `A`, the user would have to authorize each and every file difference between `B` and `C`)? Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much accurate.